# unrecognized tag-prefix in my project in asp.net control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a major problem in my project that all the **asp.net controls having error of unrecognized tag-prefix because of the all the internal tag has been converted to lower case and intellisense is not working on these control** but working on html controls, **this project is working fine on other system but not on my system**. Other projects on my system are working fine.

***I have done the following things but didn't find the solution for it:***

1. Deleted reflected schema from vs folder
2. Add tag for the asp control in web.config
3. Formatted my system.
4. Added the intellisense .js file.
5. Done the VS repair

Hoping for the positive solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: @IrishChieftain done that but this is not VS issue

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Vs version is 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel and solution is prepared in framework 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Delete the C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 folder:

[Visual Studio 2010 RTM intellisense not working for asp.net tags](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/e442ee39-fc82-4614-8f2e-374046e39edd)

Comment: Done that too deleted all vs folder

Comment: Can you give more specifics of VS version, ASP.NET version, website or WAP project, etc.

Comment: Vs version is 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel and solution is prepared in framework 4.0

Comment: Run VS in safemode - does Intellisense come back?

Comment: can u tell me how to run vs in safe mode

Comment: Run devenv /safemode in the VS console

Comment: Having same issue in safe mode too

Comment: Try: devenv.exe /resetsettings -create new project and see if it's fixed?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/91eb0d67-a4ec-4546-b4c9-29a0eaed11f2

Comment: Thanks for the link but these solution didn't helped me out

Comment: Did you try creating a new project after doing a repair install? It's probably project-specific and your project file may be corrupted.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying say other projects are working fine in my system

Comment: You could have something installed on your machine that they don't? Verify a new project after repair install first - try running in safemode after repair install and create new project; narrow it down from there...